# Angular 4 application error: "core.es5.js:1169 Uncaught Error: No provider for PlatformRef!"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am getting the following error trying to run a single page application using the browser (I have the same issue with chrome as well with safari). I am suing angular cli (angular 4) and typescript. I do have an unique component and an unique module. Using the main component I am trying to ask for some data from the backend.

The issues raised from the browser:

```
core.es5.js:1169 Uncaught Error: No provider for PlatformRef!
at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
at createPlatform (core.es5.js:4239)
at core.es5.js:4265
at core.es5.js:4262
at core.es5.js:4262
```

The error seems caused by the following line of code written inside the main component injected in the main module:
    let res =  new CalculatorCore().getMaxProfitCurrencyPath(500,      dataManager.getCalculateDataStructure("EUR"));

Here the clas CalculatorCore:

```
import { Currency } from "./currency";
import { Map } from 'collections/map';

export class CalculatorCore {

private inputOutputCurrency: string = "EUR";

constructor() {
}


getMaxProfitCurrencyPath( price: number, currency: Currency, steps?: number, path?: Currency[]):Map<number,string[]> {

let returningPath: Map<number, string[]> =  new Map<number,string[]>();

currency.getConvertibles().forEach((key:Currency, value:number) => {

    if (!steps) {
      steps = 2;
    } else if (steps > 0) {
      steps--;
      if (currency.getLabel() == this.inputOutputCurrency){
        path = [];
    }

      path.push(key);

      this.getMaxProfitCurrencyPath(price*value, key, steps, path);
    } else if (steps == 0 && key.getConvertibles().has(this.inputOutputCurrency)){
          path.push(key.getConvertibles().get(this.inputOutputCurrency));
          returningPath.add(key.getConvertibles().get(this.inputOutputCurrency)*price, path);
        }
      });

return returningPath;
   }
}
```

Here the component code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { KrakenClient } from 'kraken-api/kraken.js';
import {DataManager} from "./data-manager";
import {CalculatorCore} from "./calculator-core";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  ngOnInit(): void {
   let dataManager = new DataManager();

   let res =  new CalculatorCore().getMaxProfitCurrencyPath(500, dataManager.getCalculateDataStructure("EUR"));

   console.log(res);

  }

  constructor(){
    console.log("App-component constructor")
  }

}
```

Is there someone able to explain the error?
Thanks,

Comment: show us your component code please.

Comment: Do you have `BrowserModule` imported from your app module?

Comment: Hi, I am importing BrowserModule from my app module. You can also see the component code above in the main question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Caused by invalid `bootstrap` setup.

## Fix

Create a new project with angular-cli and compare how you are bootstraping with the latest recommended guidance by angular.

Comment: I am bootstrapping the application with the default code created by angular-cli: platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was caused by the use of collections/map.